# Stuck on a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

So im working on this php program which has a `Person` Class. There is a method inside that class called `find_by_email($email)`. I try to find a user by email, using an email address that I know for certain is in my db. After querying the db, it should return a person object.

I've already checked to make sure my table names and columns are correct. After testing it appears that the code does not pass the first if statement: `if ($r = mysql_query($query, $dbc))`.   The only thing I can think of is that my query must be incorrect. Is this not the right syntax?

here's how I call the method:

```
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$person = Person::find_by_email($_POST['email']);
```

here is my `Person::find_by_email()` method:

```
    public static function find_by_email($email) {
        global $dbc;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE email=". $email;
        if ($r = mysql_query($query, $dbc)) {
            if($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
                $person = new Person($row);
                return $person;
            }
        }else{
        $error = "Could not find user";
                echo $error;
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your MySQL query is injectable. Use prepared statements

Comment: You need to learn SQL basics. String formatting at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to enquote your variable in your MYSQL statement like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE email='$email'";
```

Comment: it is good this way, try it, it will work. this is a good MYSQL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your function ,

```
public static function find_by_email($email) {
        global $dbc;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE email='{$email}'";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $dbc)
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($num_rows) {
            if($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
                $person = new Person($row);
                return $person;
            }
        }else{
        $error = "Could not find user";
                echo $error;
        return nil;
        }
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

. . If you don't feel comfortable checking the mysql_error() to see the error message, you can output the query and run it in a visual tool (like HeidiSQL--runs on Wine on Linux as well, btw). Just do...

```
die("SELECT * FROM person WHERE email=". $email);
```

. . Copy the output and run it. It will give you the error message.

. . Right now it looks like you're not quoting the value when inserting it in the query, like:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE email=foo@bar.com
```

. . It's invalid syntax. You need to enclose it in quotes. Altough you can fix the error simply by escaping and quoting the value of `$email` variable, you should seriously consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) in most recent PHP versions for its modern features, such as prepared statements, so that you don't need to worry about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) or broken escaping functions.

. . Amplexos.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've defined `$dbc` correctly...

First of all your query string is wrong, you need quotes around `$email`:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE email='". $email . "'";
```

Second, your SQL is injectable, you need to escape the post string:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

Third, please don't use `mysql` libs as they're deprecated, search `mysqli` and read about it.

Comment: -1 for "second". Escaping and quoting are just 2 parts of string formatting, both useless one without another. And mysql_real_escape_string has nothing to do with whatever "injecting" or "post strings"

Comment: I clearly explained two core steps then recommended ditching mysql for mysqli. I have no idea why you downvoted this.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that $dbc is already opened connection to [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

```
public static function find_by_email($email) {
    global $dbc;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE email=?";
    $stm = $dbc->prepare($query);
    $stm->execute(array($email));
    if ($row = $stm->fetch()) {
        return new Person($row);
    }
}
```

note that you should never echo anything directly from the function.
check the returned value and then decide if you going to echo anything.

Comment: 5 answers, only one with prepared statements... sigh. +1